# What is this PostGIS query doing to measure the distance? How distance value is differed by the_geom and the_geom_webmercator

Tags: postgis, reprojection-mathematics

I dont know how the distance is differed based on WGS84 and  Web Mercator.

Sample:

```
SELECT *, 

ST_Distance(
    the_geom::geography,
    CDB_LatLng(35.68879039,
        139.74517892)::geography
  ) / 1000 AS dist, 

 ST_Distance(
    ST_Transform(
      CDB_LatLng(
        35.68879039,
        139.74517892),
      3857),
    the_geom_webmercator
    ) / 1000 AS distance 

FROM tblrc_geom_jp

WHERE ST_DWithin(ST_Transform(CDB_LatLng(35.68879039, 139.74517892), 3857),the_geom_webmercator,1000 / cos(35.68879039 * pi()/180))
```

Results:

```
Record 1: 
 .........
dist: 0.89083829568,
distance: 1.09980160229206

Record2:
..........
dist: 0.46739726238,
distance: 0.575471921344686
```

Why there is a difference in distance? My assumption is I should get the same distance value for dist and distance column.

Comment: The latter query makes the measument in projected space and EPSG:3857 is unsuitable for area and length measurements because of huge distortions. See https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000011356. With the geography data type PostGIS knows internally how to deal with the real World that is spheric.

Comment: Thanks for your input. As per above query I have to find list of properties within 1km radius to the given point along with distance between two points. is it safe to use ST_Distance(
    the_geom::geography,
    CDB_LatLng(35.68879039,
        139.74517892)::geography
  ) / 1000 AS dist,

Kindly help me to alter the query based on my requirements.